# Xamarin Forms - PDFTron

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, pdftron

I am building a PDF app with the use of PDFTron library. I have included the required dll files in my .iOS project (PDFNetiOS.dll and Tools.dll) and followed some examples that i found online to create my Custom Renderer. However, it doesn't seem to like this specific line which literally creates the viewer control...

`PDFViewCtrl mPdfViewCtrl = new PDFViewCtrl(this.View.Frame);`

The error message is the following: The type RectangleF is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'monotouch, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=.....
So i right clicked and checked PDFViewCtrl definition and i noticed this:

`public class PDFViewCtrl : MonoTouch.UIKit.UIView`

As far as I know, monotouch has been deprecated after version Xamarin's 2.0 version so does that mean that I cannot use this library anymore or do I probably have an old .dll and should request a later one?

Any help on this matter is truly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: it sounds like this library is built against the deprecated 32 bit library.  You should contact the vendor to see if they are supporting the new 64 bit library

Comment: Yeah I thought so. Thanks Jason, really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A new version of PDFNet for Xamarin was released yesterday, which no longer has the Monotouch dependency.